# Writing a convex quadratic constraint in SOC form

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

I am trying to apply the following transformation for a problem:

Consider a quadratic constraint of the form

$$ x^TA^TAx+b^Tx+c\leq0. $$

This is equivalent to the SOC constraint

$$ \left\| \begin{array}{c}(1+b^Tx+c)/2\\Ax\end{array}\right\|_2 \leq (1-b^Tx-c)/2. $$

The challenge for me is, my problem is in the form $x^T Q x + bx +c \leq 0$ where $Q$ is not positive definite (it is semidefinite). So I can't apply Cholesky decomposition $Q = L^T L$ and I can't use the transformation above.

I am now trying to find another method. I tried eigenvalue-eigenvector decomposition: $Q = VDV^T$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. But that doesn't give the same solution as Cholesky does.

How can I write the constraint in SOC form?

Comment: $x^TQx\leq 0$ where $Q$ is positive semidefinite is a bit silly, as that simply means $x$ has to be in the null-space of $Q$, i.e. it is a linear constraint.

Comment: It is a longer constraint actually. It is in the form $x^T Q x + bx + c \leq 0$, but the main part is that underlying $Q$ is not positive definite. Is there any ideas about how I can do this transformation?

Comment: I think you can use the eigenvalue decomposition and write it as $Q=VD^{1/2}D^{1/2}V^T=(VD^{1/2})(VD^{1/2})^T$.

Comment: Also, the Cholesky decomposition is indeed defined for positive semidefinite matrices (see wiki page, for example), you just can't use the same algorithm to compute it. An [$L D L^\mathsf{T}$](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ldl.html) decomposition of $Q$ can give a semidefinite Cholesky by breaking up the $D$ into $(D^{1/2})^2$.

Comment: Just use any factorization based on, e.g., eigenvalue decomposition, SVD, or LDL. You will have zeros in the diagonal in the middle matrix, indicating that you can remove some of the rows and thus use a compressed factorization $Q=M^TM$ where $M$ is fat.

Comment: @DavidM. I tried that. It is not giving the same thing. For example:  Q = [2 -5/2; -5/2 4]; since it is positive definite I can compare $L^TL$ with $VDV^T$. For the first one, I do L = chol(Q). Also I do [V, D] = eig(Q). However, $L \neq (VD^{1/2})^T$

Comment: @cdipaolo I think you are suggesting the same thing with David M.

Comment: @aslv95 Not quite — my comment was about getting a bonafide Cholesky decomposition since L is lower triangular, but both solutions work equally well in theory.

Comment: Hi @JohanLöfberg can you please elaborate a bit more? How does it become a linear constraint? Thanks!

Comment: The question has been changed since my comment (as you can see as I am talking about $x^TQx \leq 0$ which means $x^TQx=0$ which  for  decomposition $x^TR^TRx = 0$ simply means $Rx=0$)

Comment: Indeed, that's why I didn't get it. Thanks @JohanLöfberg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your approach using the eigenvalue decomposition is correct. In this case, we have that

$$ Q=VDV^T$$

which can be written as

$$ Q=(VD^{1/2})(VD^{1/2})^T. $$

(As noted in the comments, other decompositions could work as well, but I'll use this one, since it's the one you mention). Your concern is that, if $Q$ is a positive definite matrix, then the matrix $L$ obtained by taking the Cholesky decomposition isn't the same as the matrix $VD^{1/2}$ obtained above. However, this doesn't mean that the resulting reformulation doesn't yield the same result in both cases.

Consider your example

$$ Q=\begin{pmatrix}2&-5/2\\-5/2&4\end{pmatrix}.$$

If we take the Cholesky decomposition, then, to a few digits of accuracy,

$$ L=\begin{pmatrix}1.414&0\\-1.768&0.935\end{pmatrix}. $$

If we take the eigenvalue decomposition, then, to a few digits of accuracy,

$$ VD^{1/2}=\begin{pmatrix}-0.459&1.338\\-0.311&-1.976\end{pmatrix}. $$

Indeed, $L\neq{VD^{1/2}}$. However, let's look at the plots of the level sets for all three formulations:

[image: All three feasible regions are the same]

*Voilà*

**Edit:** A note on *why* this is true: essentially, we are employing this theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times{n}}$ be positive semidefinite, and let $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times{n}}$ be any matrix such that $Q=L^TL$. Then the sets
$$ S_1=\bigg\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \bigg|\ x^TQx+b^Tx+c\leqslant0\bigg\} $$
and
$$ S_2=\bigg\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \bigg|\ \left\|\begin{array}{c}(1+b^Tx+c)/2\\Lx\end{array}\right\|_2\leqslant(1-b^Tx-c)/2\bigg\} $$
are equal.

This result makes no reference to the form of $L$, only that $Q=L^TL$. Hence, if there exist $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that $Q=L_1^TL_1$ and $Q=L_2^TL_2$, then the sets

$$ F_i=\bigg\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \bigg|\ \left\|\begin{array}{c}(1+b^Tx+c)/2\\L_ix\end{array}\right\|_2\leqslant(1-b^Tx-c)/2\bigg\} $$

for $i=1,2$ are the same (as illustrated above), even though $L_1\neq{L_2}$.

Comment: Also, as Johan Löfberg notes, when you do this computationally with the eigenvalue decomposition, you can delete the columns of $V$ corresponding to zero eigenvalues ($0$ entries on the diagonal of $D$). This will save space and be more efficient.

Comment: That seems like a great answer. Thank you.